# Importing .style File with Incomplete Color Ramps into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, style, color-ramp

I'm running into a bit of a snag with importing a .style file into ArcGIS Pro. Some of the color ramps in the file aren't showing up entirely. It looks like ArcGIS Pro is treating all my color ramps as "Multipart color schemes" instead of the "Continuous color schemes" I was aiming for. Multipart schemes cap out at 20 colors per ramp, leaving any extras in the dust.

[image]

How do I get ArcGIS Pro to show all the colors and recognize them as "Continuous" instead of "Multipart"?